# margin: 0 auto not working in IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to center a div `#logo_alt` containing an image using `margin: 40px auto 0px auto;`.

**Problem:**: On Chrome, it looks perfect, but in IE, this img-containing div is aligned to the left of its parent container `#header_organizer`. I just cant figure out why this is happening, and how it can be fixed in IE! Any help greatly appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_organizer">
    <div id="user_bar">...</div>
    <div id="user_bar_menu">...</div>
    <div id="logo_alt">                <!-- <<<<< We are centering this div! -->
       <img src="logo.png" \>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_organizer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background: black url(../images/template/header.png);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#logo_alt {
    width: 256px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
}


#user_bar {
    height: 30px;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3000;
}

#user_bar_menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 165px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a doctype declaration?

Comment: No I dont. The HTML file start off with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`. Do I need one? And why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The HTML file start off with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.

Well there's your problem. You need to give your document an XHTML doctype declaration since your root element has that `xmlns` attribute anyway. Then IE will work in standards mode and render your `margin: 0 auto` style correctly.

Comment: Will this `doctype` do? `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Fun fact: contrary to popular belief, IE6 *can* render `margin: 0 auto` in standards mode. It's IE5.x that can't. IE's quirks mode emulates IE5.x, not IE6, since IE6 has its own standards mode. But of course, it's 2012 now, and nobody will read or vote on this comment. Walruses, platypuses and unicorns.

Comment: I like platypuses. Unicorns goes without saying. Walruses hog the bed a little too much. `BoltClock.Answer.Comment[2].UpVote();` anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, add a `doctype` to prevent IE from slipping into quirks more.

Then try this...

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```